# Path following algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math

Say I have a shape that looks like this:

```
 __ __
|__|__|
```

There are 7 line segments each 2 units long.

Each has an (x, y) coordinate for the beginning and ending segment on the line.

The lines might be stored in an array like so:

```
[
    [0, 0,  2, 0],
    [0, 0,  0, 2],
    [0, 2,  2, 2],
    [2, 0,  2, 2],
    [2, 0,  4, 0],
    [2, 2,  4, 2],
    [4, 0,  4, 2]
]
```

All these lines are connected. How can I determine that these specific lines (ALL of them) are connected given there are other lines that aren't connected.

Basically I can't figure out anything that gets all the lines.

If anyone can point me in the right direction either conceptually or code wise that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear, "connected" here means that you can start at any vertex & reach any other vertex only by tracing along the lines?

Comment: I'm not so sure, but what about checking that each (x,y) coordinate exists only two times? If it's true, it means that all the line are connected.

Comment: Your array does not represent your drawing. In your array you have a diagonal line fro (2,2) to (4,4) absent in your drawing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438865

Comment: I second @phs question. Can you explain better what you are trying to distinguish?  Maybe give examples of two minimally different drawings/structures that your algorithm needs to distinguish.

Comment: Consider each beginning and end point as a vertex, each line as an edge, then just do a graph traversal (either BFS or DFS) starting from any vertex and check if you visited all of them. If you want to find multiple connected sets of lines you can do [connected component labeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling)

Comment: If this is simply about finding a [connected component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29), doing a BFS or a DFS works just fine.

Comment: @phs yes that is correct

Comment: @Bdloul That might work. Possibly looping through the array looking for vertex matches?

Comment: @maxhud : It should work if you just change one thing : ".... exists at least two times".

Comment: @Bdloul I assumed that was implied. Hopefully that works. I'll get back soon

Comment: What if you have [0, 0,  0, 4] and [0, 2,  2, 2]?  Does that count as "connected" for you, even though any of the verteces aren't actually shared?

Comment: The above should read "even though **none** of the verteces are shared among the two segments."  I guess it would be good to know if you are limited to vertical and horizontal lines, and in general how you want to deal with crossing lines: do they count as connected or not?

Comment: @angelatlarge I am limited to horizontal and vertical lines and lines cannot cross.

Comment: @Bdloul if you post this as a solution i will accept

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the transitive closure of a graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438865/finding-the-transitive-closure-of-a-graph)

Comment: @Bdloul: Your algorithm is wrong I'm afraid. Consider 8 lines arranged into 2 4-line loops: every vertex appears twice so your algorithm will say they are connected, even though the two loops are not connected *to each other* (false positive). Your algorithm will also wrongly report that any path (i.e. any sequence of edges, including just a single edge) is not connected, because the two endpoint vertices each appear only once (false negative).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A naive Perl version:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $l = [ [0, 0,  2, 0],
          [0, 0,  0, 2],
          [0, 2,  2, 2],
          [2, 0,  2, 2],
          [2, 0,  4, 0],
          [2, 2,  4, 2],
          [4, 0,  4, 2] ];

my @f;
Segment:
while (my $line = shift @$l) {
        for my $set (@f) {
                push (@$set, $line), next Segment if is_conn($line, $set);
        }
        push @f, [$line];
}

for my $set (@f) {
        print "\n================\n";
        print join(",", @$_), "\n" for @$set;
}

sub is_conn {
        my ($line, $set) = (shift, shift);
        for my $cand (@$set) {
                return 1 if has_same_point($cand, $line);
        }
        return 0;
}

sub has_same_point {
        my ($l1, $l2) = @_;
        my @p11 = ($l1->[0], $l1->[1]);
        my @p12 = ($l1->[2], $l1->[3]);
        my @p21 = ($l2->[0], $l2->[1]);
        my @p22 = ($l2->[2], $l2->[3]);
        return is_same_point(@p11, @p21) ||
               is_same_point(@p12, @p21) ||
               is_same_point(@p11, @p22) ||
               is_same_point(@p12, @p22);
}

sub is_same_point {
        my ($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2) = (@_);
        return $x1 == $x2 && $y1 == $y2;
}
```